# (Installshield 2010) How can I register MIME Type?

Tags: iis, mime-types, installshield-2010

I need to register some MIME types in IIS.

I cant find any options on Installshield 2010 but (Component-any component- Advanced Settings-File types) tab has some MIME @#$@% thing. I dont know exactly it can really do what i want.

Does anyone know about this????

Comment: You need to be more specific - IIS6? IIS7, Both?

Answer (score 0):

In Installshield you can select in the "Installation Designer" tab, On the tree (docked at the right) the "Organization" > "Components". There, i advise to pick one of the main components that are always installed.

There you have the second tree (with the Component list). Select "Advanced Settings" > "File types" > "Extensions". Right click and select "Add new extension". Add the extension without the dot.

Lets suppose your application opens *.bla and have the class id {3b001638-42be-4fa0-8440-0089d83ea7a7}

Add the extension "bla", create new MIME type under it. Add the class id {3b001638-42be-4fa0-8440-0089d83ea7a7}

Save the Installshield project, build and test it.